# Basic calculus on topological fields

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces, differential-calculus

Let $K$ be a a topological field (I am mainly interested in the cases when K is either an ordered field or a valued field, e.g. $K = \mathbb Q$ or $ \mathbb Q_p$).

1) Let $f: K^n \to  K$ be a function such that its differential $Df$ is constant $0$.
Is $f$ constant on some non-empty open set?
(Notice that it's easy to produce a function as above for $K = \mathbb Q$ such that $f$ is not locally constant at $0$).

2) Let $f: K^2 \to K$. Assume  that the functions $\partial f / \partial x$ and $\partial f / \partial y$ exist and are continuous.
Is $f$ $\mathcal C^1$?

Comment: No to 1:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski's_question_mark_function